# What kind of compiler optimization would violate language standards?

Tags: c++, arm

I was reading the [arm compiler user guide](https://static.docs.arm.com/100748/0609/compiler_user_guide_100748_0609_00_en.pdf), on page - 42. It mentioned that on -Ofast and -Omax level of optimization, the ARM compiler might violate strict compliance with language standards. I am wondering why and how. Can someone help please? I am using C++ for my project and I am investigating different compiler optimization options.

Comment: It's probably related to floating point arithmetics. It's hard to refactor floating point arithmetic expressions because it can change the result slightly, even for operations that seem intuitively invariant. For example, `x*y + x*z` seems like it's equivalent to `x(y + z)` but with floating point rounding it might have subtly different results. A lot of applications wouldn't care about those difference and would prefer that the compiler uses the faster version.

Comment: [This reference document](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_sbt1475153708426.htm) says `-Omax` uses `-ffp-mode=fast` and [this page](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_rni1489589347476.htm) lists some possible compliance violations that `-ffp-mode=fast` may cause. This is probably not exhaustive though. Edit : I'm not sure if this is the same compiler you are using, but at least it's a hint.

Comment: It'll probably start using NEON floating-point, which is severely non-ieee754.

Comment: if it is some sort of mission critical thing you should not be using an optimizer.  Otherwise you need to have some sort of regression or smoke tests to validate each binary before release.

Comment: @old_timer If it is mission critical, you shouldn't be using garbage code that breaks the rules of the language. I wouldn't trust any code that breaks at `-O3` to do *anything* correctly.

Comment: @EOF well perhaps times have changed then because you would never consider such a thing in the past.  You cant validate a compiler with optimizations to meet these standards.

Comment: gnu -O3 is not expected to work in general, if it does, good, -O2 is.

Comment: @old_timer If you're paranoid (or lives depend on it) I'd recommend *testing* at `-O3` and then *running* at `-Os` or `-O2`.